# How to show for the user of my jhipster application only the entities that he had created?

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I'm creating a jhipster application and I want to let my user access only to the entities that he created, for example in my case I just want to have for each user a special view of the entities product that he created and not for all the products created by other user.
Thank you in advance,
Waiting for your help ...

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Security Expression-Based Access Control ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html

Comment: Thank you this is a very interesting documentation! but steal don't know how to do it and in witch file  exactly should I make the modification  specially  that I'm a beginner

Answer (score 1):

JHipster does not provide that type of filtering, you'd have to implement it yourself. Out of the box, the only thing you can do is play with the security roles, both in the front-end and the back-end (as pointed out by @gaël-marziou).
In the front, using `authorities` in the state declaration (entity.js file). In the back, using `@Secured` in the controllers (EntityResource.java).

In order to the type of filtering you need, you have to create new attributes in your entities to store the user that he/she created, and then create new methods in your repository to do proper queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it is more clear now, I will try to do it. When I'm looking in the spring-security documentation I found some thing like : "@PreAuthorize('isOwner(#someEntity)" would this be useful in my case ??